# Getting 404 Not found when trying to expand events on the reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

If you look at the [reputation events of a user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172552/martin?tab=reputation), and try to expand a post, you'll get an "Error occurred when loading post body" message, probably because the URL that is being polled returns 404.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/ajax/users/172552/martin/rep/post/123796/1330450472/1330450530?_=1330450586489
```

[image: screenshot]

**EDIT:** It seems that this was fixed.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123801/155556

Comment: Who voted to close this? How can **this** be duplicate of another one which didn't exist?

Comment: That one has since been closed as a duplicate of this one. Ignore the close vote, it's not longer applicable.